# differential equation and general solution of it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ have a continuous derivative at every point in $\Bbb R$. let be $c$ be a real number. also, $v(x)$ is the solution of the differential equation $y'=f(y)$.
Then, I was wondering about the following statement:

> $y=v(x+c)$ is a general solution of $y'=f(y)$

I think that it is not true but I am not sure how to prove it or give an example in order to counterproof it. Any ideas?

Comment: Since $v'(x)=f(v(x))$, if $y_1(x)=v(x+c)$ then $y_1'=v'(x+c)=f(v(x+c))=f(y_1)$. So $y_1$ is a solution of the ODE. $v(x+c)$ is a one parameter family of curves which is the solution of first order ODE.

Comment: first, thank you. secondly, so according to what you said it is true but how can you say that ′1=′(+)=((+))=(1) before knowing it is really a solution? I mean before knowing it is a solution you can't substitute it in y'=f(y) or am I wrong?

Comment: Any $y$ that satisfies the ODE is a solution. You can show that if $v(x)$ is a solution then $v(x+c)$ is also a solution i.e. $v(x+c)$ satisfies the ODE.

Comment: yes but how is it that you know it satisfies the ODE that's what I wonder about?